# Disable edit menu in WooCommerce category Admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable the edit menu in WooCommerce category Admin panel. My code is:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
  if( has_term( 'product_cat' ) ) {
    unset($actions['edit']);

    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    return $actions;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried Googling But I cant find my answer. How can I fix it?

Comment: You might find an answer to your question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110782/remove-categories-tags-from-admin-menu

Comment: @jmarkmurphy  Kindly, wordpress.stackexchange.com **is just an only** for **pure WordPress questions** that don't involve any plugin or any third party themes… It will be nice to remove your comment… thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code in function.php file

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');

function hide_category_buttons() {
   $texonomy = isset($_REQUEST['taxonomy']) ? $_GET['taxonomy'] : "";
   if($texonomy =='product_cat'){
    echo '<style>
    .row-actions .edit {
       visibility: hidden; display:none;
      }

   .row-actions .hide-if-no-js {
    visibility: hidden; display:none;
    }
  </style>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Admin menu editor pro](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) for the same.